# Google fonts in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I am trying to use Google fonts in a Visualforce page.  Google offers three ways to use their fonts:

1. `<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
2. `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef);`
3. `<script type="text/javascript">
        WebFontConfig = {
           google: { families: [ 'Alef::latin' ] }
        };
        (function() {
           var wf = document.createElement('script');
           wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
            '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
           wf.type = 'text/javascript';
           wf.async = 'true';
           var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
         })(); 
     </script>`

## Problems with above approaches:

1. When I try this option, I get an error that `<link>` needs to be closed with a `</link>` tag (even when I enclose this and the CSS styling around `<head>` ... `</head>` [I've read that `<head>` and `<head>` get ignored anyways when the VF page is interpreted into HTML.]).  If I try to add a `</link>`, the fonts don't display.  Also, I've tried an `<apex:stylesheet value="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef">`  with no luck.
2. This option doesn't work either.  I've thought of trying to download the CSS and saving it to a static resource, but I haven't been able to accomplish this either.
3. This method **does** work.  However, when the page loads, there is a quick glitch when loading the page where the Javascript is processing the font -- which is undesirable.

Are there any ways to use option (1) or (2) that I'm missing?

Comment: On #1, what gets rendered in the final output from the apex:stylesheet component? Also, have you tried <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> (note the trailing slash)

Comment: Yea, I tried that, and the Google font never renders.  I just tried now not using the "http://" in front of the link, and it didn't work for me either.

Comment: What about saving #1 css as a static resource and then import it with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{!$Resource.RESOURCENAME}" />` or `<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.RESOURCENAME}" />`?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do that from Google.

This is what fonts.google.com/css?family=Lobster gives:

   ` @font-face {
        font-family: 'Lobster';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: local('Lobster'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lobster/v5/MWVf-Rwh4GLQVBEwbyI61Q.woff) format('woff');
}`

Maybe the issue is with the **woff** format or the url for the .woff file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with a bit of tinkering. I'm not a pro (or even an amateur) at CSS, but I wasn't able to style using elements. I had to use class ids instead.

```
<apex:page >
  <apex:stylesheet value="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef"/>
  <style>
      .alef {
        font-family: 'Alef', serif;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    </style>
  <body>
    <div class="alef">Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: changing **http** to **https** was the trick!